# Java Date - Android Time Picker

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I'm having trouble getting the right format here.  I'm trying to get a proper date from my android date picker to shove into a date object.

For example:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
```

Those event handlers will give me: 2011, 7, 5 10,30 (if the date was August 5th, 2011 and the time was 10:30)  Where do I get Am/Pm in Android?

I'm doing this but its not working right:

```
Date date = new Date(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth,hourOfDay,minute);
```

I need to accomplish the Android equivalent of this blackberry code.  Blackberry date picker graciously provides a date object (rather than raw integers):

```
public void run() {
            DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance();

            // Set the max time to 24 hours into the future. This allows for selecting clips
            // across time zones, but prevents the user from wandering off into no-mans' land.
            Calendar maxDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDateTime.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24*3600*1000));
            datePicker.setMaximumDate(maxDateTime);

            if (datePicker.doModal())
            {
                Calendar selectedDate = datePicker.getDateTime();
                Date beforeDate = selectedDate.getTime();
                ClipStore.getInstance().getClips(camera, beforeDate);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Calendar :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

The hour of day goes from 0 to 23.

Comment: How do I get a date object from a calendar? There is no .getDate() method

Comment: Sorry. It's getTime(), as you could have discovered by browsing the Calendar javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29

Answer (score 0):

I believe that hourOfDay uses 24-hour time, so it should be a value between 0 and 23 inclusive.  If it's greater >=12, it's PM.

Answer (score 0):

By stock the Java.util will use Military time. aka 10:30 refers to 10:30 AM. 10:30 pm will be shown as 22:30. If you want to convert it to pm try something like this:

```
public String ampmChanger (String time) {
  int hour = (int)time.substring(0,2);
  String timeAppendage;
  if (hour > 12) { // For 1 PM and on
    hour -= 12; 
    timeAppendage = " PM"; 
  }
  else if (hour == 12) timeAppendage = " PM"; // For 12 pm
  else timeAppendage = " AM"; // For 0(12AM) to Noon

  return String.valueOf(hour)+time.substring(2)+timeAppendage;
}
```